# Buggy behaviour of spoiler tags when they contain both text and images

Tags: bug, markdown

I know that we don't use the [spoiler syntax in Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers) very often, but it seems it's a bit buggy, at least on this site.

Consider the following test of the spoiler tag, containing both some text and an image:

```
>! This is a test of the spoiler tag.

>! ![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vECQ8.jpg)
```

This displays incorrectly, and it just registers as a normal blockquote:

> [image]

This behaviour goes away if you separate the text from the image with, say, a horizontal rule, but this is hardly ideal:

> [image]

---

It seems to me that this is buggy behaviour and ought to be fixed (and also fixable relatively easily?).

Answer (score 3):

Buggy indeed. Utill its fixed, here is a workaround:

> After the text, insert an invisible `$${}$$.` $${}$$ [image]

Comment: Yeah, that looks OK - as a workaround. I don't particularly mind the original bug but I still think that it's something the team might want to fix, which is why I reported it ;-)